# I want to create custom child window for about application (for windows) in electron js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, menu, electron, electron-builder

I want to create a child browser window to display some points about my application. Acc. to electron js docs it supports for Mac OS  the "about" role but does not support anything for windows. So, I'm creating a custom window for windows. And I have created a window but I don't know how to render html in that. Anybody aware of that please provide some solutions. I'm adding my code I have done so far. Thanks.

```
    const childURL = `file://${__dirname}/index_child.html
    let child = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    modal: true,
    show: false,
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
    minimizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    fullscreenable: false,
  })
  child.loadURL(childURL)
  child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    child.show()
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use file protocol yourself.
you can use `loadFile` method.

or if you still want to use the file protocol. you are missing a slash.

`` const childURL = `file:///${path.resolve(__dirname, "index_child.html")}` ``

```js
let child = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    modal: true,
    show: false,
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
    minimizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    fullscreenable: false,
});

child.loadFile("index_child.html");

child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    child.show()
})
```